Failure in code of perl module installer "cpanp" [ERROR] Dir '' does not exist
I know this question may not pass the moderator filter but I cannot find another corner of StackOverflow where it would be welcomed.
I am seeing a very bizarre failure in cpanplus, which uses many OO Perl features. I am rubbish at debugging OO Perl, as the error messages are so often cryptic if not downright misleading.
Here is what I did and what I saw:
$ sudo cpanp -i -v String::Escape
[sudo] password for XXXXXX: 
[MSG] No '/root/.cpanplus/custom-sources' dir, skipping custom sources
[MSG] No '/root/.cpanplus/custom-sources' dir, skipping custom sources
[MSG] No '/root/.cpanplus/custom-sources' dir, skipping custom sources
[ERROR]  is not a proper distribution name!

No such module: 
Installing String::Escape (2010.002)
==> MISSING Signature file! <==
[ERROR] Dir '' does not exist

Key 'dir' () is of invalid type for 'CPANPLUS::Internals::Utils::_chdir' provided by CPANPLUS::Module::Signature::check_signature at /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1/CPANPLUS/Module/Signature.pm line 61.
[ERROR] Dir '' does not exist

Key 'dir' () is of invalid type for 'CPANPLUS::Internals::Utils::_chdir' provided by CPANPLUS::Dist::_resolve_prereqs at /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1/CPANPLUS/Dist.pm line 835.
Running [/usr/bin/perl -MCPANPLUS::Internals::Utils::Autoflush /root/.cpanplus/5.28.1/build/3BQT_XTtFd/String-Escape-2010.002/Makefile.PL]...
[ERROR] Could not run '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL':  -- cannot continue

[ERROR] Dir '' does not exist

Key 'dir' () is of invalid type for 'CPANPLUS::Internals::Utils::_chdir' provided by CPANPLUS::Dist::MM::prepare at /usr/local/share/perl/5.28.1/CPANPLUS/Dist/MM.pm line 441.
[ERROR] Could not chdir back to start dir ''

[ERROR] Unable to create a new distribution object for 'String::Escape' -- cannot continue

*** Install log written to:
  /root/.cpanplus/install-logs/String-Escape-2010.002-1734840648.log

Error installing 'String::Escape'
Problem installing one or more modules

I'd greatly appreciate any help, advice, or obscure insight ;-).

"I am seeing a very bizarre failure in cpanplus" : Can you also try with cpan and cpanm?

There could also be some corrupt config files in /root/.cpanplus/. You could try take a backup of that folder, then delete it and then retry the command (cpanp should then regenerate the folder).

Do you really have ** in your command, or is that just formatting that you did not remove?

You guessed it TLP.  It was markup that snuck in there, I meant to emphasize the command but StackExchange apparently doesn't do such a thing inside code blocks (which sorta makes sense I guess ;-)

Håkon, in fact I tried the same module with cpan and it also failed, in its own way. AFAICT, cpanminus (cpanm) is still working. I tried removing the files under /root/.cpanplus but this did not fix the problem; I get the same error. And @brian d foy, thank you for fixing my erronious markup - I was going to do that but found you had beat me to it. It's an honor to have one of the keystones of perl development looking at my posting. Thanks :-)

@amphibole "I tried removing the files under /root/.cpanplus but this did not fix the problem" One way to approach this issue is to set up docker container, and do the same installation there. If it fails there too, then others can also try reproduce and help you with debugging. If it does not fail there, the problem is likely related to your particular machine and its setup

I tried installing String::Escape with cpan and had no problems. If you showed the output of cpan failing I might be able to help.
